# Cleanly morph SVG paths

Tags: svg, raphael

In [this fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/h8DWE/6/) I am trying to morph the small H into the big H by simply extending the ascender. I thought it would be as simple as just providing the new path and letting Raphael work its magic, but apparently that's not the case.

Is there an easy way to elongate the ascender without having it mangle up first? Note this is one moving piece out of a much larger logo.

Comment: have you looked [here](http://raphaeljs.com/animation.html)? it may help sidestepping this by creatively approaching the animation process - check out the source to see how they did it (though i don't see a way of achieving what you're after as animation of paths is hard-wired into the implementation).

Comment: yes i have looked at that, specifically at the square that smoothly turned into a triangle, but couldn't really determine what it was that did it.

Comment: it seems this mechanism is pretty much opaque. another idea is to cut the logo horizontally and use separate shapes (and *paths*) for the top and bottom halfs, that way you can scale only the top (as i assume you aim for that).

Comment: i also considered that, but even that has the same issues, as "growing" the ascender either involves scaling or morphing, which will result in the same kind of garbling

Comment: scaling alone won't do that. you can even leave the serifs unmangled and scale only the mid-high range.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As far as I can see from the draw path, the two shapes are not drawn from the same starting point - so you're getting mangling.

SVG animation will always try to morph the first segment of the start shape into the first segment of the end shape. If the draw order is different, then you'll get strange effects like what you're seeing.

(And please note that you must have the same number of segments and the same order of path types in the start and end shapes.)

Comment: ohhh... that makes sense. so all i have to do is make sure the order is the same. hm ok thanks. i'll try this out